# How do I display an Image without 2 exports?

Tags: android, css, reactjs, react-native

Hello I tried to display an image on my welcome screen but I can't seem to be able to do it.
I followed this doc : [enter link description here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image)

I tried to only export `export default DisplayAnImage;` instead of the Default app export but I can't make 2 exports and I know.. But I don't know how it really works for the exports and maybe there is a better and simplier way to display an image (and still be able to make it fit and apply settings on it)

What should I do ?

```
import {
  Button,
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  LogBox,
  Image,
} from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={{ fontStyle: "italic", fontSize: 30 }}>
        Bienvenue !{"\n"}
      </Text>

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Mon écoute")}
      >
        <Text style={styles.acces}>ENTRER</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

const DisplayAnImage = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.image}>
      <Image
        style={styles.tinyLogo}
        source={require("C:/Users/Noah Drui/Documents/course 2 js/my-project/pics/logo.jpg")}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

function DetailsScreen() {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: "center",
        marginBottom: 540,
        justifyContent: "center",
      }}
    >
      <Text>Quelle est votre humeur aujourd'hui?</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Accueil" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Mon écoute" component={DetailsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginBottom: 80,
    alignItems: "center",
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
  },

  acces: {
    position: "relative",
    marginTop: 5,

    fontSize: 15,
  },

  button: {
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#2B92FF",
    borderRadius: 15,
    borderWidth: 0.3,
    borderColor: "#000000",
    width: 300,
    height: 30,
  },

  tinyLogo: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
  },

  logo: {
    width: 66,
    height: 58,
  },

  image: {
    paddingTop: 50,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: and the export default DisplayAnImage; did worked but only displayed my picture. (my path is right) and I saw there is some other methodes but I can't seem to link my .jpg file with a uri

Comment: How you are planning to use `DisplayAnImage`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `DisplayAnImage` is a React component in this case.

Considering you want to display it on your `HomeScreen`, try actually using the component inside the page that is beign displayed from App:

```
const DisplayAnImage = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.image}>
      <Image
        style={styles.tinyLogo}
        source={require("C:/Users/Noah Drui/Documents/course 2 js/my-project/pics/logo.jpg")}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={{ fontStyle: "italic", fontSize: 30 }}>
        Bienvenue !{"\n"}
      </Text>

      <DisplayAnImage /> /* place it wherever you want inside the view */

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Mon écoute")}
      >
        <Text style={styles.acces}>ENTRER</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Leave the `export default App` as it is the only one that actually needs to be exported.